# Download a epub

Tags: node.js, epub

I am trying download a epub that I have generated on my server. I am using NodeJS (and angular).

In Node I am doing this:

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.readFile('book.epub', function(err, content) {
    if (err) {
        response.writeHead(400, {'Content-type':'text/html'});
        response.end("No such file");
    }
    else {
        response.setHeader('content-type', 'application/epub+zip');
        response.end(content);
    }
});
```

And on the front end I do this:

```
var binaryData = [];
binaryData.push(file);                        
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(binaryData, {type: "application/epub+zip"}));
a.download = "book.zip";
a.click();
```

When I open the downloaded zip, it creates a new zip. What I am missing?

Comment: What does the `file` denote in the `binaryData.push(file);` statement?

Comment: It's the return object from response.end(content)

Comment: Did you check for its length?

Comment: Yeah quite big, 72400. The beginning looks like this:  PK-XdImimetypeapplication/epub+zipPKoa�,PK-XdIMETA-INF/container.xml]��
�0D%�U��MBӂ�W�b���t74���=T�6�yo�j�w�cҰ*� �,��z
�ӮX�h��2%�ǿn�)j�FRl���̀Q%�8 �l�)�OM����9u�c�F�M������vs8�7���Cb�֙"=j0!xgM�G$�%Čٛ�q��@֕���y�~PK�-���PK-XdIOEBPS/0_no-title.xhtmlMP;O1��+Lv��,ʥ&e`L/n5�����{�����ò����+��b�ن�`h�q�\�����=۩��yz��>��R��y*0JC��

Comment: Shouldn't `a.download = "book.zip";` be `a.download = "book.epub";`